# How to run multiple executable files , with in a single docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Since we can only have one ENTRYPOINT AND CMD in a Dockerfile, how can we run multiple executable files?
Consider the following case:
Docker copies two cpp files and compiles them generating two executables.
The ENTRYPOINT will define run one file with cmd giving arguments for it.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM gcc:11.3.0

# Copy the current folder which contains C++ source code to the Docker image under 
/root/sonu
COPY . /root/sonu
    
# Specify the working directory
WORKDIR /root/sonu
     
    
# Use GCC to compile the Test.cpp source file
RUN g++ -o Tests tests.cpp
RUN g++ -o  Testd testd.cpp

     
#entrypoint for executing the executable file
ENTRYPOINT ["./Tests"]
 
CMD ["10","3"]
```

Following is the code for first file (tests.cpp)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
    
    
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << "You have entered " << argc
         << " arguments:" << "\n";
    
    if (argc != 3) {
        cerr << "Program is of the form: " << argv[0] << " <inp1> <inp2>\n";
        return 1;
    }
    float n1= stof(argv[1]);
    float n2= stof(argv[2]);
    float sum =n1+n2;
     
    
    cout << "Result: " << sum << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

This one is for subtraction (second test) - Subtraction testd.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << "You have entered " << argc
         << " arguments:" << "\n";
    
    if (argc != 3) {
        cerr << "Program is of the form: " << argv[0] << " <inp1> <inp2>\n";
        return 1;
    }
    float n1= stof(argv[1]);
    float n2= stof(argv[2]);
    float diff =n1+n2;
    
    
    cout << "Result: " << diff << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

### Intended Output

I'd like to be able to run either of the executable with command line arguments given to them.

**PS**:
Creating multiple docker images isn't feasible as the entire image would be memory heavy and the binary files which are being shipped are less than 200 MB

Comment: Typically you'd use multiple containers for this.  It's somewhat easier to set this up if you use `CMD` instead of `ENTRYPOINT` in the Dockerfile; then you can `docker run your-image ./Testd` to launch the second binary.

Comment: https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/dockerfile-entrypoint-vs-cmd/

supplimental link

Comment: "Creating multiple docker images isn't feasible" I beg to differ. A docker image is supposed to do one thing and one thing only -- otherwise, orchestration becomes problematic.

Answer (score 1):

How about you call a script from your `ENTRYPOINT` instead of a single executable file ?

The script could simply call any executables you want. You will need to import it in the image in your Dockerfile.